# HTML5 localStorage & SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, html, local-storage

I understand that HTML5 "localStorage" is a *key:value store* but I am wondering if there is a Javascript library available that offers a more *SQL-ish* API?

Comment: [This post][1] might be helpful to you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260127/is-there-a-free-lib-accessing-to-html5-database-sqlite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [Will HTML5 be SQL-free?](http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2009/12/will-html5-be-sql-free.html) and [DOM Storage: a Cure for the Common Cookie](http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2009/05/dom-storage-cure-for-common-cookie.html) for some links and opinions.

Comment: Good reading in those links, thanks! I am also just going to add an article linked to in one of those that gave a good perspective on the usage of SQL for the browser storage > http://blog.vlad1.com/2009/04/06/html5-web-storage-and-sql

Answer (score 5):

[W3C Database specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/#databases) says:

> User agents must implement the [SQL dialect](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) supported by Sqlite 3.6.19.

As of now, *at least* Google Chrome supports SQL dialect. I have [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391761/local-databse-storage-default-data/2391868#2391868) myself.

Comment: I am using 5.0.342.1 dev version of Chrome.

Comment: Around November 2010, the document now reads "This document was on the W3C Recommendation track but specification work has stopped."  The IndexedDB document now supersedes it - http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

Answer (score 3):

You should use HTML5 database storage (it supports SQL through transactions).
a tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/

Comment: Time and tide keep washing over HTML5. It seems like WebDatabase is out and indexDB is in. Here's the updated article by the same author: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 local database storage comes with a SQL interface by default, if I'm not mistaken

Here is a Webkit post with some examples: http://webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/

Currently, Chrome forces you to use Gears, which is slightly different, but still SQL-based. Future versions of Chrome will follow the HTML5 spec, however.

Comment: See 4.11. Client-side database storage - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/2007-10-26/#sql

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://kailashnadh.name/code/localstoragedb/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql). It supports standard SQL language and keeps data in memory or localStorage.
There are sevelar ways, how to use Alasql with localStorage. Below you can see how to create localStorage database with name "Atlas", attach it to Alasql as "MyAtlas", then you can work with tables like any other database. By default, Alasql uses AUTOCOMMIT ON mode, so it saves data to localStorage after each SQL statement.

This is a sample:

```
alasql('CREATE localStorage DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Atlas');
alasql('ATTACH localStorage DATABASE Atlas AS MyAtlas');
alasql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyAtlas.City (city string, population number)');
alasql('SELECT * INTO MyAtlas.City FROM ?',[[{city:'Vienna', population:1731000}, 
    {city:'Budapest', population:1728000}]]);
var res = alasql('SELECT * FROM MyAtlas.City');
```

Play with this sample in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/x1gq3wf2/). Run this sample two or three times (or reload page), and you will see, how the number of lines will grow in the table.