# Local Database Storage default data

Tags: html, local-storage

I have developed application using HTML 5 Localstorage.

How can I create a TABLE and populate 10000+ rows before initializing my
HTML 5 enabled application.

Please suggest a pattern.

Comment: check my answer. tell me if it doesn't help

Comment: would be awesome if this post was tagged with "localStorage" also ;)

Comment: localStorage is a simple key value store, but I believe what OP might want is the local *SQL database*, **not** *localStorage*.

Comment: sqlite probably help to solve your problem. follow the ans given by N 1.1 for downloading the whole code visit my link http://blog.developeronhire.com/create-sqlite-table-insert-into-sqlite-table/ hope this will help

Answer (score 5):

```
var db = openDatabase('dbname', 'dbversion 1.0', 'description', 64*1024);
db.transaction(function (query){
   query.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (id unique, value)');
   var rows = 10000, i;
   for(i=0; i < rows; i++){
      query.executeSql('INSERT INTO tablename (id, value) VALUES ('+ i + ', "Stackoverflow")');
   }

   query.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tablename', [], function (query, results) {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         alert(results.rows.item(i).text);
      }
   });
});

//Do magic with your webapp now
```

The queries accepted are [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) type. Check the [official specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/#databases) for more.