# Where can I find a definitive reference on HTML 5 database SQL syntax support?

Tags: database, reference, html, client

Does anyone know of a good online resource which gives a clear reference on the SQL syntax supported by HTML 5 client-side databases? I've looked about and cannot seem to locate one.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878256/html5-localstorage-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a working draft, but you can read more about it here - http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/

You might be interested in this too - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/

Answer (score 0):

the short answer: http://sqlite.org/lang.html

the long answer: the sql-syntax isn't in the spec, because it's entirely defined by [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), the db-engine used by both safari and chrome (the two browsers to support webdb, with opera probably following soon(ish) [and ms and mozilla refusing to follow just because of the fact that such a spec would be too dependant of the evolution of an external component](http://blog.futtta.be/2009/11/18/chrome-opera-to-support-html5-webdb-ff-ie-wont/)). so you'll probably want to look at the sqlite sql dialect?