# Non-Deprecated localStorage with SQL-style Queries

Tags: sql, indexeddb

It looks like there was a question similar to what I have here back in 2009:
[HTML5 localStorage & SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878256/html5-localstorage-sql)

However, a lot changes in 4 years, so I was hoping to hear some up-to-date information on this. It looks like WebDatabase is officially deprecated, and I've looked into IndexedDB, and I'm not too impressed, its ability to query seems primitive in comparison to SQL.

Feels more like I'm working with a linked list than with a database.

So my question is if anyone has created some sort of interface to a supported localStorage implementation(ideally more or less future-proof) that will let me run SQL-style queries?

I suppose I should add that I'm mostly just interested in maintaining syntax across code, since I'll be using an SQL backend, I'd like to be able to essentially just copy and paste the database code from the backend for the offline capabilities of the front-end.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'll take an Active Record equivalent as well, if anyone has that.

Comment: you realize localStorage is sooooo small that you can just do a full scan of all the data within milliseconds right

Comment: It's more the ease of coding than the speed I'm worried about. I'm already going to be writing SQL for the actual backend, why not just copy/paste the code for the front-end's offline features?

Comment: No, there is nothing like that, because nothing like that makes any sense at all. You don't want something as heavy as an SQL adapter sitting on top of your 5mb of localStorage space. Wanting such a thing, just so you can use a familiar SQL-like syntax on top of a store that doesn't look anything like a relational database is *crazy*. You're adding an enormous layer of complexity on top of something which is dead simple.

Comment: This is also off-topic, both as a possible duplicate of [HTML5 localStorage & SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878256/html5-localstorage-sql) and because you're asking for links to off-site resources.

Comment: Well, it apparently made sense enough that Web SQL Database is perhaps the best supported on mobile browsers and all browsers outside Firefox for that matter, even though it's technically depreciated.

Comment: Web SQL is a **completely** different thing, designed specifically to be queried via an SQL-like query language. It's not comparable to writing a wrapper to let you query localStorage via SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) library. It is a JavaScript SQL engine with internal localStorage support, so you can use 'good old' SQL to persist data in browser:

```
alasql('CREATE localStorage DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Atlas');
alasql('ATTACH localStorage DATABASE Atlas AS MyAtlas');
alasql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyAtlas.City (city string, population number)');
alasql('SELECT * INTO MyAtlas.City FROM ?',[[{city:'Vienna', population:1731000},
     {city:'Budapest', population:1728000}]]);
var res = alasql('SELECT * FROM MyAtlas.City');
```

THis is a [sample in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/x1gq3wf2/)

Comment: It will be nice if alasql load data from indexeddb.

Comment: Hope we can prepare async version of Alasql with support of IndexedDB  and WebSQL in two weeks.

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely much closer to what I was looking for originally. Hope the project continues strong!

Comment: Thank you! Now we finished with async version (version 0.0.30) with limited support of IndexedDB, and will continue to optimize by speed and memory usage.